# How do I reliably pause the state of a game?

Tags: timer, libgdx

So I have a couple instances where I want to be able to 'freeze' the state of my game. It's a top-down scroller, and I want to give the player the ability to pause the scrolling of the screen for a short time by using a powerup (if you fall to the bottom of the screen you die). I also want to pause the game as it is starting, and draw a 3, 2, 1, go! to give the player time to get ready, because right now as soon as you hit play, the screen starts scrolling.

I have been using Timer to accomplish this, however it doesn't work if I want to freeze the screen on consecutive occasions. Like if a player uses a freeze, the screen sucesssfully freezes, but if they quickly use another freeze, it doesn't work. There seems to be an unintended cool-down. I have a similar problem for the 'intro delay' I explained earlier. For some reason it only works on the first 2 levels. Here is how I am using Timer.

```
  if(gameState != STATE.frozen) {
        camera.translate(0, (float) scrollSpeed);
        staminaBar.setPosition(staminaBar.getX(), (float) (staminaBar.getY()+scrollSpeed));
        staminaMeter.setPosition(staminaMeter.getX(), (float) (staminaMeter.getY()+scrollSpeed));
        healthBar.setPosition(healthBar.getX(), (float) (healthBar.getY()+scrollSpeed));
        healthMeter.setPosition(healthBar.getX(), (float) (healthMeter.getY()+scrollSpeed));
        boostBar.setPosition(boostBar.getX(), (float) (boostBar.getY()+scrollSpeed));
        boostMeter.setPosition(boostMeter.getX(), (float) (boostMeter.getY()+scrollSpeed));
        screenCeiling += (float) scrollSpeed;
        screenFloor += (float) scrollSpeed;
    }
    else {

        Timer.schedule(new Task() {         //freeze the screen for 5 seconds

            @Override
            public void run() {

                gameState = STATE.playing;

            }
        }, 5);

    }
```

From what I understand, it waits 5 second before resuming the game to the 'playing' state. But like I said, this only works when activated between large intervals and I don't know why. Is there a better way I can be doing this?

As for the intro delay, this may be a question better asked seperate, but I use the same method, but it doesn't let me draw sprites over my tiledmap, so if anyone knows how to do that please include it in your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the code you posted is in your render loop, then whenever you are not in the frozen state, you are creating a new timer task on every frame. So if you freeze for 5 seconds and your game is running at 60fps, you will create 300 timer tasks, each of which is going to force the game to go back to playing state. The last one won't fire until 5 seconds after the first one fires, so there will be a five second "cooldown" during which you cannot change the state to anything besides `playing`, because there will be another timer task firing on every frame during that time.

You need to ensure that you only create one timer task, only when you first enter `frozen` state.

I do have a suggestion...instead of using a state to freeze the game, use a variable that's multiplied by `scrollSpeed`. Change that variable from one to zero when the player uses the powerup. Then you can do fancy stuff like quickly interpolating from one to zero so the speed change isn't so abrupt. And it will probably make your code simpler since there would be one less state that must be handled differently in the algorithm.

Comment: how is it creating a timer 300 times if it only is allowed to when the game is in a frozen state? Because I have it set up if(not frozen) scroll, else (new timer). and it only becomes frozen if the player picks up an item and presses space. Or are you saying once it is frozen it is creating 300 timers, I think I get it then

Comment: `render` is called over and over. When you first enter `STATE.frozen` it will create a timer when it gets to this point in the code. One frame later, you are still in `STATE.frozen` when it gets to this point in the code, so another timer is created. This will keep happening on every frame until the very first timer finally fires and changes the state to `playing`. Now on every frame, another timer is going to reach its limit and fire until the very last of the 300 timers is done. Only then will you be able to change the state and have it stick.

Answer (score 0):

Check your gameState variable in the render method and if the game is playing, then update the game as usual and draw it.

If the game is not playing then skip the game's update method and create a time delay from the current time:

```
endTime = TimeUtils.millis()+5000;
```

Then each time through the render method check to see if current time is greater than the end time. When the current time is past your delay time, set gameState back to playing and have the game go back to updating.

You'll have to have another boolean flag so you only set the endTime once (you don't want to keep resetting this each time through the render loop), or if "STATE" is an enum, then include an option for "justPaused" for the exact frame that you pause the game, set the end time, then set STATE to "notPlaying".

You can also use this to create an alternative "update" method where you can update your countdown sprites, but not update the game itself. When the game is playing this other update method will be skipped.